# Sql Insert Error -"Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below code i have pass multiple values with comma Separated to @i_CustomerGroupID and one value to  @i_LocationID.In which i face a issue "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.".Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertCustomerGroupLocationMap]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @i_LocationID int,
    @i_CustomerGroupID varchar(100)

    --WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerGroupLocationMap WHERE LocationID = @i_LocationID AND CustomerGroupID = @i_CustomerGroupID)
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO CustomerGroupLocationMap (LocationID, CustomerGroupID) VALUES (@i_LocationID, (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_CustomerGroupID)));

    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `insert . . . select`:

```
    INSERT INTO CustomerGroupLocationMap(LocationID, CustomerGroupID) 
        SELECT @i_LocationID, t.*
        FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_CustomerGroupID) t;
```

Your function `dbo.CSVToTable()` returns more than one value (I assume there is only one column).  The correct syntax is the `insert . . . select`.

As a note, `insert . . . values` is really not needed.  You can use `insert . . . select` even when you only have constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 FROM CustomerGroupLocationMap WHERE LocationID = @i_LocationID AND CustomerGroupID = @i_CustomerGroupID)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO CustomerGroupLocationMap (LocationID, CustomerGroupID) VALUES (@i_LocationID, (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_CustomerGroupID)));

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rewrite both your exists query and the insert query-

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerGroupLocationMap WHERE LocationID = @i_LocationID AND CustomerGroupID IN (SELECT *
    FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_CustomerGroupID) ))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO CustomerGroupLocationMap (LocationID, CustomerGroupID) 
    SELECT @i_LocationID, i.* FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_CustomerGroupID) i;

END
```